# Check if checkbox in NOT checked in a Jinja2 template

Tags: html, templates, jinja2

In my jinja2 template I have a list of checkboxes. Initially they all should be checked. Then the user can uncheck some of them for filtering out things.

```
<p><input name="name1" type="checkbox" checked /> blabla1 </p>
<p><input name="name2" type="checkbox" checked /> blabla2 </p>
<p><input name="name3" type="checkbox" checked /> blabla3 </p>
<p><input name="name4" type="checkbox" checked /> blabla4 </p>
<p><input name="name5" type="checkbox" checked /> blabla5 </p>
```

If, for example, the 1st checkbox in unchecked, I need to get the `name1` and its value (smth like "off" or "false") in the list of arguments (`request.args.keys()`) anyway. 
So far if the 1st checkbox is unchecked, I just don't have it in the list of args:

```
/query=somequery&blabla2=on&blabla3=on&blabla4=on&blabla5=on
```

How can I do smth like this in a jinja2 template:

```
<p><input name="name1" type="checkbox" {% if checked %}
                                           value="on" 
                                       {% else %} 
                                           value="off" 
                                       {% endif %} /> 
        blabla1 </p>
```

And to get all of the arguments with corresponding values:

```
/query=somequery&blabla1=off&blabla2=on&blabla3=on&blabla4=on&blabla5=on
```

My app is on Flask/Werkzeug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I managed to sort it out by myself. Here is how I did it:
         1. Give all the checkbox the same name
2.Attributes different values to each checkbox:
    `

```
    <p><input name="type1" type="checkbox" checked value="val1"/> blabla1 </p>
    <p><input name="type1" type="checkbox" checked value="val2"/> blabla2 </p>
    <p><input name="type1" type="checkbox" checked value="val3"/> blabla3 </p>
    <p><input name="type1" type="checkbox" checked value="val4"/> blabla4 </p>
    <p><input name="type1" type="checkbox" checked value="val5"/> blabla5 </p>
```

3. In my app code :
   Compare the list of arg values to the "initial list" with the set of all possible values. If something is missing - add it to a new list for further processing. 
   `ar = request.args`

   ```
   > #This will produce a structure of this kind
   > ImmutableMultiDict([('query', u'q'), ('type1', u'val1'),
   > ('type1', u'val2')])

   > #Then I just get a list of values of 'type1' with the getlist function:

    imd = ar.getlist('type1')
    lst_init =['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5']


   > #and compare the 2 list adding unchecked items to the newlist
   newlist = []
   for x in imd:
      for y in lst_init:
         if y not in imd:
            if y not in newlist:
                  newlist.append(y)
   ```